# How to read grib file by netcdfAll

Tags: scala, grib, netcdf-java

I am moving from

```
"edu.ucar" % "netcdfAll" % "5.0.0-beta2"
```

to

```
"edu.ucar" % "netcdfAll" % "5.4.1"
```

and I see that function, which I use to open `.grib2` files

```
NetcdfDataset.openDataset(path)
```

is marked as deprecated. What is new way to open it?

Comment: You should probably ask the maintainer of this library on GitHub if they haven't provided an explanation for the deprecation in the scaladoc. I doubt this is a library sufficiently known for someone here to be able to answer.

Comment: Thank you for a tip I found answer on their github :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after digging I found it.. according to https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-java/wiki/Common-Client-Changes it was moved to `NetcdfDatasets.openDataset(path)`